# Bad PayPal Digital Goods Express Checkout experience in Mobile Safari (iPad): popups are opened as tabs

Tags: javascript, ipad, paypal, mobile-safari, in-app-purchase

I have been implementing [PayPal Digital Goods Express Checkout](https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_api_IntroducingExpressCheckoutDG) in my (HTML5) web app to enable the 'in-app' purchase of extra app content. In my desktop browsers (Chrome, Safari, Firefox) the digital goods flow works without problems. In that flow popup windows are opened at some points, for instance when the user clicks the login button or the button to pay with his creditcard (i.e. without having a paypal account). The popups are no problem for the desktop browsers. However, in Mobile Safari on my iPad 2 **popup windows are always opened as (new) tabs**, even if a property string containing width, height, etc. is passed to a JavaScript window.open() command. This makes it impossible to implement PayPal Digital Goods Express Checkout and have a good user experience in both desktop browsers and Mobile Safari. When the web app is run full-screen on the iPad (using an icon on the home screen) opening the popups becomes even more problematic (or impossible).

In trying to solve my problem I came up with the following options, none of which has yet led to satisfying results:

- Customize the payment flow. Of course this is possible to some point, but after having redirected the user to the 'incontext' Express Checkout page that forces the user to login to PayPal, customization is out of my hands (as far as I know). For instance, I cannot       customize the login process itself and make it work in an iframe (instead of a popup window) instead. It would be cool if there were some advanced API commands that I could use server-side to make the user login to PayPal myself, using my own (iframed) login form, but    this seems too far-fetched.
- Make popup windows work like expected in Mobile Safari, preferably also when a web app is run full-screen. I don't think it strange that Mobile Safari opens new windows as tabs (there are other browsers that do this). I *do* think it is strange that popup windows that are opened from JavaScript, using window.open and a property string that defines the window's position and dimensions, are opened as tabs. Does anyone know how to make Mobile Safari open such popup windows normally without requiring the users to change some browser setting?

To demonstrate my problem (and show that I am not the only one facing it, though this site's owner probably doesn't know it ;-), go to [digitalmagazine.autosport.com](http://digitalmagazine.autosport.com/) with your iPad and click the 'Pay with PayPal' button at the top-left of the page. Click the login button in the PayPal iframe. The site disappears and the login page (that is supposed to be opened in a popup window for an 'in-app' experience) opens full page.

I have also looked at the client side (JavaScript) techniques that are used by [similar in-app payment systems](https://developers.google.com/in-app-payments/), but those (understandably) also use popup windows. Therefore I would prefer the second solution that I have described above. That one will also involve much less work.

Comment: Did you ever get to the bottom of this?

Answer (score 2):

While PayPal supports the mobile platform, you will need to make some changes to fully implement it for iOS and other mobile operating systems.  You will find the PayPal Mobile overview here:  https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_api_ECOnMobileDevices

The process starts with changing the redirect command in Express Checkout flow to _expresscheckout-mobile, and then steps through a list of additional requirements for full implementation.  Read the documentation carefully, as it can be a bit picky when it comes to supported NVP fields.

Comment: I have thought of Express Checkout Mobile but decided not to use it since I do not think that it allows for a real 'in-app' (i.e. web app) experience. By that I mean that, in the payment flow, the user is redirected to the PayPal pages and the app disappears until the user finishes the payment and is redirected back to the app. The popup system of the Digital Goods Express Checkout runs 'on top' of the web app, that is its big pro.

Comment: @Jeroen we are also grappling with DG deficiencies from our 'partners' at Paypal. I'd suggest that angry calls to execs and product management is the only way to go at this stage. They clearly don't get it.